# Facebook Inline Chat for Ruby on Rails to run on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I've been looking for an inline chat to integrate with my app, but everything available that I found runs on PHP servers. I found the two:

- CometChat
- JQuery + PHP chat - anantgarg

This is exactly what I'm looking for but to use Ruby on Rails and to run on Heroku.

Can someone please suggest a plugin or service I can make use of on Rails that will integrate my app users in private chats on my website?

Thanks,

SS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [Pusher](http://pusherapp.com/)?

Comment: may be... but I can't find how to integrate it on Heroku even though the example seems to be running on Heroku server :(

Answer (score 3):

If you want IM functionality like that you should look into [Juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: thanks this is something I will be able to use on my project!

Comment: I was hoping that I don't have to re-invent the wheel. I guess no one has published something that makes use of Juggermaut in a inline chat? :(